# How to map objects in store (with redux-thunk)

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

*Hi, I want to iterate an object in array by redux, redux-thunk*

The problem is, the global state (store) cannot iterate by `Array.map()`

Here is the example of tutorial https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-pike-q0449

Here is my version https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-thunk-fetch-6wsr8

The difference are ...

at **asynchronous action creators**

```
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1') //tutorial: return 1 object
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')   //my experimental: return array of object
```

and **UI Component**

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

// Tutorial------------------------------
{content.data && (
  <ul>
    <li>{content.data.id}</li>
    <li>{content.data.title}</li>
  </ul>
)}

// My Experimental------------------------ ERROR: content.map is not a function.
<ul>
  {content.map(todo => (
    <li key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

I have searched for a solution. I found `React.Children` but I am not sure for use it in this case.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you need

```js
const content = useSelector(state => state.data || []);
```

You can get rid of the default empty array by initializing data as `[]` in the initial state

```
function reducer(state = { data: [] }, action) {

}

// now access data
const content = useSelector(state => state.data);
```